# Case insensitive query

Tags: elasticsearch, case-insensitive

Im using ElasticSearch, and I have this field:

```
"name": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
},
```

I run this query to get, for example, all employees with the name "Charles":

```
GET company_employee/employee/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
                "match_phrase": {
                   "name": "Charles"
                }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

The issue with this is that I need to get an insensitive search. I need to retrieve all "Charles", even if the value I provide to the query es ChaRleS or charles, or CHarles, etc. What I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If reindexing is not an option, this leaves altering your query

Although the [regexp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) approach doesn't allow for searching case insensitive, you could do so "manually".

If the character is always the first letter, you can get by with this:

```
GET company_employee/employee/_search
{
   "query": {
         "regexp": { "name": "[Cc]harles" }
    }
}
```

Otherwise for "true" case-insensitive:

```
GET company_employee/employee/_search
{
   "query": {
         "regexp": { "name": "[Cc][Hh][Aa][Rr][Ll][Ee][Ss]" }
    }
}
```

This is in no way efficient, but matches your constraint of not altering the index.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you'd rather need to have your `name` field to be analyzed, i.e. like this:

```
"name": {
  "type": "text",
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

With such mapping all your values will be lower-cased, thus search will be case-insensitive.

Comment: Are you able to recreate your index with the above-mentioned index-mapping applied?

Comment: Sorry I made a fast-read of your answer ;)
I can't remap. There's no other solution? Nothing that can be added to the query to get it done?

Comment: Well, basically the classic approach is to make lower-case both at index and query time. The idea you need to match the value from your index with the value from your query. Lower-case normalization is the easiest and most used technique. You can come up with your own normalizer (aka analyzer / filter) though.

Comment: How do you suggest to make that re-indexing?

Comment: I'm assuming you've put your data to ES from some data-source (i.e. database). If you are able to pull your data from database once again - then I'd simply recommend creating new index with Index API (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/indices-create-index.html#mappings). In case if you want to make ES to reindex its indices (not touching database) you could use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html OR https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime#_reindexing_your_data_with_zero_downtime approaches.

Comment: Im trying this to update the field:
PUT company_employee/_mapping/employee
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "standard"
    }
  }
}

And got this error: error": "MapperParsingException[No handler for type [text] declared on field [name]]",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141450/discussion-between-paul-vasilev-and-david-tg).